# Form is not getting submitted due to `change` event attach to a input field

Tags: jquery

I have a form a submit button and a input field that has a `change` event.
Now when I edit something in input field and try to submit the form. The form is not submitting.Only change is getting fired. 
Sample code is as follows

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input type="text" id='text_field' value="123" />
<button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('change', '#text_field',function() {
 /*
 do some ajax call for calculation.
 */   
 });
```

Comment: Think your only mistake is that the "button" should be an input.
EG. <input type="submit"  value="Submit" />

Comment: Okay, Lets make it button as <input>, Its not working. I have tried. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

`form` tag is missing `method="post"` attribute.

Try the following **HTML** instead:

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id='text_field' value="123" />
<input type="submit" >Submit</input>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think adding 'post' will do the job. The problem is when i make changes in input field , and try to click submit button the change event is getting fired. I want first 'change' event and then submit event.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit your form with Jquery then Try this..

```
<form>
<input type="text" id='text_field' value="123" />
<button type="button" id="form_submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jquery

```
$("#form_submit").click(function(){

  text_field = $("$text_field").val();

 $.ajax({
          /*
         do some ajax call for calculation.
         */
        })
 }
```

Comment: I don't see, How this is gonna help my problem?